# Geometric Interpretation of Classical Probabilistic Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose we have an integrable function $f$ defined over $[0, +\infty]$ with integral 1. Define the function
$$ g_1(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x) \, dx. $$

At its core, what Markov's inequality suggests is that, given the value $k = g_1(f)$, it is possible to give a "covering function" or "envelope", i.e. a function $f^*_k$ that bounds every function in $F_k$ (functions $f$ such that $g_1(f) = k$).

In probability theory, it seems beneficial to find good "envelopes" - those that cover the functions tightly. This leads to my first question:

1. Knowing $g_1(f)$, is the "envelope" given by Markov's inequality, defined as
   $$ f^*_k(x) = \begin{cases} 
   1 & \text{if } x \leq k, \\
   \frac{k}{x} & \text{otherwise,}
   \end{cases} $$
   the best possible?

Secondly, my understanding is that we can frame this problem as follows: Assuming I can create a function $g_1: F \to \mathbb{R}$ that will "summarize" my function into a constant, and I'm looking to create the function $g_1$ giving me the most information about my function $f$ (in the sense that it lets me create the "best envelope"), is it possible to choose a better function than
$$ g_1(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} xf(x) \, dx $$
to summarize $f$?

2. If we define the notion of the "best envelope" more globally, as the one which minimizes the integral underneath the envelope, do we have a guarantee that choosing $g_1(f)$ as above gives us the best possible envelope?

Thirdly, from what I understand of Bienaymé-Tchebychev's inequality, it offers an even better envelope than Markov, but under the constraint of knowing the aforementioned integral $g_1(f)$ and $g_2(f)$, where
$$ g_2(f) = \int_{0}^{\infty} (x - g_1(f))^2 f(x) \, dx. $$
Is there a guarantee that the given $g_1$ and $g_2$ are optimally chosen among possible $g_1$ and $g_2$ functions?

3. Is it possible to extend this trend? If we know $g_i = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^i f(x) \, dx$ for $i$ from 1 to $n$, can we design an even tighter envelope? Even better, is there a guarantee that as $n \to \infty$, our envelope approaches $f$?

In general, I am opening this post to see if there are probability theory courses/books that present the material from this perspective or if there are other fields in mathematics that define similar constructs.

EDIT : Actually, the "envelope" is not majoring the density function but the cumulative function. But the core of the argumentation stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found yesterday, (thanks to GPT-4 !) [Moments, Positive Polynomials and Their Applications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255658272_Moments_Positive_Polynomials_and_Their_Applications) by Jean-Bernard Lasserre that formalizes and studies the problem ! Here is a short extract of the book that properly formalizes the problem :

Generalized Moment Problem (GMP):

Let $K$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mathcal{M}(K)$ be the space of finite *signed* Borel measures on $K$, whose positive cone $\mathcal{M}(K)_+$ is the space of finite Borel measures $\mu$ on $K$. Given a set of indices $\Gamma$, a set of reals $\{\gamma_j : j \in \Gamma\}$, and functions $f, h_j : K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, j \in \Gamma$, that are integrable with respect to every measure $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(K)_+$, the GMP is defined as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{GMP} : \quad \rho_{\text{mom}} = \sup_{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(K)_+} \int_K f d\mu \\
\text{s.t.} \quad \int_K h_j d\mu \leq \gamma_j, \quad j \in \Gamma.
\end{aligned}
$$